# Is there a way to disable post meta caching for development?

Tags: post-meta, cache

I find that the post caching system is very inconvenient while I am developing plugins. I can't waste time waiting for the correct value of certain post meta to be displayed.  Is there any way to disable the post meta caching system completely or to at least change the amount of time between data refreshes?

Answer (score 1):

There's no caching system in WordPress core that would cause the issues you're having.

The post meta cache ([WP_Object_Cache](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache)) is not persistent. Its purpose is to ensure that meta data is only loaded once per page, not every time `get_post_meta()`, for example, is used, but it does not cache those queries across page loads. Therefore refreshing would be all that's required to get the new data. If post meta isn't updating immediately it would be because you're running a caching plugin of some kind, like W3, Redis, APC, Memcached. So the solution there would be to disable the plugin.

If you're not running any of those your host might be doing something on their end. In that case you'd need to talk to them.